# Using a text editor other than the Google Apps Script default

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to to work on a project in Google Apps Script (GAS), and using their built-in IDE/editor is not satisfactory for a number of reasons. Before I list these, my question is whether I can use a different editor/development environment that the one Google provides (without having to copy/paste my code from that editor, of course).

I use NeoVim for everyday work, so I would like to be able to use something with at least Vim emulation or, better yet, to be able to sync my GAS files to my project being hosted online, without having to leave my normal editor.

The built-in IDE for GAS is weak, with no obvious documentation/keyboard shortcuts that I've come across, which makes even switching between script files a small chore. 
This all goes without mentioning the difficulty with debugging (although [betterlog](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/betterlog) makes this almost tolerable).

I feel like I must be missing something huge (a tutorial maybe) because I feel like Google would be one of the first to acknowledge developer comfort/laziness when building their tools.

Answer (score -1):

If you can also use Eclipse, there is a helpful example guide of how to do so for GAS projects within the Google Apps Script documentation

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/apps_script

perhaps there is something in there for you to adapt.

Comment: Been there. Done that. But how do I debug or run from inside eclipse? Or is that not possible?

Comment: Google has dropped support for Apps Script inside Eclipse. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24740378/512127