# GoogleAppsScript - Autocompletion within Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there a way to get autocompletion for Google Apps Script in Webstorm or any Jetbrains IDE?

I have read, [that it's possible for ecplise](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.de/2013/10/total-eclipse-of-apps-script.html).

Can i get the GAS library somehow into Webstorm? Or what exactly would I have to do, to get the autocompletion to work? :)

Answer (score 7):

A similar question you can refer to:
[How do I use WebStorm for Chrome Extension Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997468/how-do-i-use-webstorm-for-chrome-extension-development/25466708#25466708), the only difference to the referred answer is in *step 5*, try to search for `google-apps-script` (instead of `chrome`).

Install the library and open `gs` files as JavaScript.

Then you are going to have grammar highlighting and autocompletion.

Comment: to find out how to use `clasp` locally, which will convert your project gs files to js, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739294/does-google-apps-script-support-external-ides for example

Answer (score 4):

How about using TypeScript instead of pure JavaScript?

Definition file for GAS is available here.
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/6723

I haven't tried it yet but I'm planning to try it.
I've just started using GAS and am exploring GAS now.

**P.S**
In order to code GAS, this article may be helpful.
http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.jp/2015/12/advanced-development-process-with-apps.html

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm (and any JetBrains IDE with the JavaScript plugin) can now handle this automatically by using TypeScript community stubs. The details are in [Configuring JavaScript Libraries - Help - WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html).

Follow the instructions on that page under **To download TypeScript definitions in the Settings/Preferences dialog**. Search for the TypeScript community stub named `google-apps-script`.

WebStorm will try to guess the type of variables based on the context, but you can also tell it explicitly. For example this tells WebStorm that thread is a GmailThread. So `getLabels` could be autocompleted.

```
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Gmail.GmailThread} thread
 */
function getThreadInfo(thread) {
  thread.getLabels()
}
```

FYI, You can search for TypeScript community stubs and get more information on each one at https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked around as well but haven't found anything yet. I don't think so, but I could be wrong. In order to get it to work, you could reverse engineer the Eclipse plugin, which I'm guessing won't be straightforward.