# how to fold code inside google script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor, clasp

does anyone know how to fold code inside google app script editor ?

it's very hard to read/debug long code inside online editor.

I did some search on google and I couldn't find any result related to this matter.

Comment: You cannot. The alternative is local development using clasp. Consider also using multiple files and functions with a single responsibility.

Comment: thanks. It's hard to believe why google forgot to add such a feature

Comment: [There is a feature request for this under Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64307043). You can help to increase visibility for this issue by starring it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in 2022 this has been added as a built in feature in google appscript editor (new version) , no additional things are required

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I did upvote the other answer that also says this.  Look at that one and see how he included more information and how-tos so that the answer was more useful to others.   Just for future reference.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland LOL 
more information does not mean it's the correct answers. other 2 answers suggest using vscode and how to add plugin to vscode to make appscript work inside VSCODE, not inside GOOGLE APP SCRIPT editor.
my requirement was to fold/unfold code inside GOOGLE APP SCRIPT editor it self , not somewhere else. 
so this is the 100% correct answer even for future as well.

Comment: Brandon's answer occurred before yours, correctly references the Apps Script editor and provides detailed instructions on HOW to get the code to fold.  It is the superior answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options for folding/unfolding (AKA "collapsing and expanding") sections of code in the Google Apps Script editor without adding a browser extension nor using an external editor.

Simply use: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `[`

To view other methods, open the Command Pallet by doing one of the following while in the editor:

- `F1` key and type `fold`
- Right-click in the editor area and select "Command Pallet", then type `fold`

From there, you can either click on the command you'd like to execute, or finish typing the phrase followed by `enter`, or using your arrow keys to select the command followed by `enter`.

[image: Apps Script Editor Command Pallet Dropdown Menu - fold]

You may similarly unfold code by typing the word `unfold` instead or using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `]`

[image: Apps Script Editor Command Pallet Dropdown Menu - unfold]

Another option to quickly toggle folding/unfolding while in the editor is to:

- go to an area/scope of code where you'd like to work
- hover over the area where you'd fold/unfold that area of code
- hold the `alt`/`option` key, and click.

[image]

That will toggle between folding/unfolding all other areas of code besides the one you are working on. GAS remembers the last action you took (fold vs unfold) so sometimes it may require a couple clicks to get the desired result.

One last point which is related to this: You can define regions in your code that you'd like to be foldable. Folding/Unfolding that area will affect all code within it.

```
//#region My Custom Region
function myFn1() {
  // Some code here.
}
function myFn2() {
  // Some code here.
}
//#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Apps Script editor compared with Visual Studio Code<sup>1</sup> and other IDEs is very limited. Since Google added [CLASP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) to Google Apps Script "family" it's very unlikely that it will be added as a built-in feature but maybe this could be added by using a web browser extension.

On the Chrome Webstore there are already some Chrome extensions that extends the Google Apps Script editor but I don't know if already exists one to add code folding.

Notes

1. VSC is mentioned that is should be used for code auto-completion in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript

Related

- [External Editor Support for Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24739294/1595451)

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview