# security warning after npm installation

Tags: windows, npm-install

On a Win10 machine, I am trying to set VS code as an external editor for Google Sheets scripts.
Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739294/does-google-apps-script-support-external-ides) I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxdCIbeO4Uk)  I installed *npm*.
Not sure exactly what *npm* if for, however after installing I get some security issues.
Installation output log:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1037 packages from 459 contributors and audited 1109 packages in 71.081s
found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

executing `npm audit` as suggested output the following:

```
                  === npm audit security report ===                        


                                 Manual Review                                  
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             
                                                                                
          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           


  Low             Prototype Pollution                                           

  Package         minimist                                                      

  Patched in      >=0.2.1 <1.0.0 || >=1.2.3                                     

  Dependency of   webpack [dev]                                                 

  Path            webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar >        
                  fsevents > node-pre-gyp > mkdirp > minimist                   

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1179                             


  Low             Prototype Pollution                                           

  Package         minimist                                                      

  Patched in      >=0.2.1 <1.0.0 || >=1.2.3                                     

  Dependency of   webpack [dev]                                                 

  Path            webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar >        
                  fsevents > node-pre-gyp > tar > mkdirp > minimist             

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1179                             


  Low             Prototype Pollution                                           

  Package         minimist                                                      

  Patched in      >=0.2.1 <1.0.0 || >=1.2.3                                     

  Dependency of   webpack [dev]                                                 

  Path            webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar >        
                  fsevents > node-pre-gyp > rc > minimist                       

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1179                             

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities in 1109 scanned packages
  3 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

`npm audit fix` fails to fix the issues:

```
npm WARN inquirer-autocomplete-prompt@1.0.1 requires a peer of inquirer@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 19.198s
fixed 0 of 3 vulnerabilities in 1109 scanned packages
  3 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
```

[npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1179) describes a bit this issue.

executing  `npm version` reports :

```
{ 'apps-script-starter': '4.20.0',
  npm: '6.9.0',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '35.1',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '64.2',
  modules: '64',
  napi: '4',
  nghttp2: '1.39.2',
  node: '10.16.3',
  openssl: '1.1.1c',
  tz: '2019a',
  unicode: '12.1',
  uv: '1.28.0',
  v8: '6.8.275.32-node.54',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

Question:
What should I do to fix it, if at all?

Comment: Looks like this was solved here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226745/npm-warn-notsup-skipping-optional-dependency-unsupported-platform-for-fsevents

Comment: @dreamwork801 I'm not sure. The **warnings** messages looks similar. However, I also get 3 **vulnerabilities** that this post does not mention.